# component property failing unit test despite being defined

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to write unit tests for a component I created. Unfortunately, there is a field we're testing and it's turning up `undefined` in the HTML despite me giving it a dummy field of the same name. In my case, it's `mastheadConfig` that is showing up `undefined`.

Here is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { IMastheadConfig } from 'lib-components';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shell',
  templateUrl: './shell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shell.component.scss']
})
export class ShellComponent implements OnInit {

  public mastheadConfig: IMastheadConfig;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <masthead [config]="mastheadConfig">

    <!--This is where the error occurs-->
    <div *ngIf="mastheadConfig.customContent">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>

  </masthead>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the test file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { IMastheadConfig } from 'lib-components';

import { ShellComponent } from './shell.component';

fdescribe('ShellComponent', () => {
  let component: ShellComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ShellComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ShellComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShellComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.mastheadConfig = {
      avatar: {
        name: 'Namey McNameFace'
      },
      customContent: false,
      search: true,
      clientLogo: {
        type: 'icon',
        iconClass: 'icon'
      },
      actions: []
    };
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should tests input', () => {
    console.log("mastheadConfig: " + component.mastheadConfig);
    expect(component.mastheadConfig).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

The tests themselves doesn't seem to fail--but when I run the tests, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'customContent' of undefined` for both of the tests.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You `fixture.detectChanges();` *before* you've set the value. Where's this supposed to come from in real life?

Comment: Honestly, this was generated from `angular-cli` so I didn't think much of it. I deleted that line and now the tests pass. Post your comment as an Answer please.

Comment: Could you also explain why this was causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mastheadConfig.customContent` expression implies that there is `mastheadConfig` component property. If it's not there, then

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'customContent' of undefined

is thrown.

`fixture.detectChanges()` triggers change detection and causes the expression to be evaluated before `mastheadConfig` component property was set.

Instead, it should be:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShellComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    component.mastheadConfig = {...};

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```